# Document set Library issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, document-set

I have created a document set library. By the time any of users create an item they can not view the documents as they should. I can see the documents, as site owner but not other users.
Could anyone advice what could be causing it?
Thanks for the time.
James

Comment: Have you looked at their permissions to the Document Library that the document set is in? It should be inheriting from that

Comment: Based on policy they have been assigned as contributors with no delete.

Comment: Is it possible that Item Level Permissions has been turned on for the document library? If they have contribute access it could block viewing of some items, but they should be able to see their own. there is no GUI method of turning on Item Level Permissions, however can be done programmatically, so could be part of it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that other users have permissions to the documents sets in the library.

[image]

If you have enabled Content Approval in this library, make sure files are approved  or check the draft item security setting:

[image]

Comment: Hi BeerusDev, the permission level as I'd stated is steel contributed. I think I should change that to members for this lib.

Comment: Hi Hartraf, I'm not sure what you meant by programmatically, since it should not occurred from the very first place. Document set is there to be used by any users and visitors to the SharePoint site. Maybe it all about the level of permission that I have set up. I'm planning to change it to members to see the differences. Thanks. James